# References for Infinite Galois Theory

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory, topological-groups

What are some "standard texts" on infinite Galois theory? I feel that Dummit&Foote only has a really brief introduction to infinite Galois theory. At the very least, I need a reference to clarify the Krull topology on the groups, preferably with an introduction to topological groups. Introducing that topology in a somewhat categorical way could also be helpful.

If knowledge about topological groups are a "prerequisite," I would also like to see some references specifically about that. I have studied a bit about pointset topology but nothing in particular about topological groups.

Comment: See "Field Arithmetic" by Michael D. Fried & Moshe Jarden

Comment: Look at the Galois groups of infinite cyclotomic extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{F}_p$, then generalize. Of course learn the $p$-adic and profinite integers if you didn't know it.

Comment: Chapter 3 of "Galois Theories" by Borceux and Janelidze may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who suggested a reference. I eventually used J.S. Milne's [Fields and Galois Theory](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/), which is freely available online and very readable.