# Examples for Infinite Galois theory

Tags: galois-theory

I've been writing something on Infinite Galois theory using mainly the notes "Infinite Galois theory" of Keith Conrad.
There are three to four main examples. Mainly $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\mid\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^{\infty}})\mid \mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1},\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5,...)\mid\mathbb{Q}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{F}}\mid\mathbb{F}$.
What are some more examples of infinite Galois extensions. Are there any other good pdf's on the matter?
Thanks!

Comment: There is also Milne's text, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4053477/references-for-infinite-galois-theory?rq=1). It is "very readable". On the other hand, I don't think that Keith Conrad's text is not enough.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Like you don't know how to construct many more, or you want some additional examples useful to discuss the difficulties (topology) of their uncountable profinite Galois group?